# Can't fuse two patterns to serve a specific purpose

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've created a pattern to scrape emails out of some list which meet certain conditions. To make it concise I applied the pattern on some emaillist to filter the expected ones instead of scraping emails from a directory.

I've tried like:

```
import re

emaillist = ['alex@10mates.com.au','sales@1300easyisp.com.au','jquery@3.4.1','info@ace.com.au','helpdesk@airtel.net.au','info@aussieit.net.au','logo@3x.c185d295.png','nr@seenError']

# pattern = r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+(?:jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)'
pattern = r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+(?:com|net).+'

def filter_emails(email):
    email = re.findall(pattern,email)
    if email:
        return email[0]
    else:
        return "criterion not met"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for email in emaillist:
        print(filter_emails(email))
```

Few of the strings contain `png`, `jpg` e.tc. which more or less looks like an email which I wanna get rid of. My commented out pattern can do the opposite, meaning it grabs those strings which have those aforesaid suffix. However, the pattern that I've used to isolate the desired emails does the trick but they may not always contain `com` or `net`.

***Question:*** How can I fuse the two patterns in such a way so that It will prioritize (not emphasize as the two suffix may not always be there) those strings which contain `com` or `net` but ignores them which contain `png`, `jpg` e.t.c.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a negative lookahead `(?!` to check if what is after the last dot is not any of the extensions:

```
^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.(?!jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)[^\s.]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L0cDdS/1)

Comment: Yeah, it works partially. Things go wrong when your pattern encounters `jquery@3.4.1` and that is the reason I wanted to include this logic within it as well `+(?:com|net).+'`. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt Can you add to the regex101 link what you exactly want to allow and not? You might use a pattern like `^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[a-z]{2,}$` to not match  `jquery@3.4.1` See https://regex101.com/r/Pft01Z/1